# imagecreatefromstring issues with string passed from javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am having issues sending an image as a string between Javascript and PHP. So far I have:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASAQMAAAByySynAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAP0lEQVQImWNgPm9gwAAmbM4bH4AQzAdAYiDC/rzxByTi/+f/cIL
```

as the string which is being passed from the JS to PHP and this is verified as the image will load in chrome "as is".

I am using PHP to then

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

This however just errors, If I remove the data:image/png;base64 bit, it works but when it comes to the larger files, this just does not work.

I'm just wondering what I could have missed here.

Comment: Did you remember to [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) the data before you pass it to `imagecreatefromstring()`

Comment: I did try that but that didn't work at all. It works with just passing

`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASAQMAAAByySynAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAP0lEQVQImWNgPm9gwAAmbM4bH4AQzAdAYiDC/rzxByTi/+f/cIL`

Comment: @ChristopherBuckley: You're lying (or not pasting the correct data here). Just passing that string will get you: Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Data is not in a recognized format in /code/Bce4M2 on line 6
An error occurred. - see http://codepad.viper-7.com/Bce4M2

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the header that is spat out from the canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");

you can either do it with javascript:

```
var imgData= canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
var postData = {drawing:imgData.substr(22)};
```

or with php

```
substr($_POST['drawing'],22);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but if I try this :

```
echo '<img src="'.$data.'"/>';
```

Then the picture is displayed...

Into a shell this does not work :

```
echo 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASAQMAAAByySynAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAP0lEQVQImWNgPm9gwAAmbM4bH4AQzAdAYiDC/rzxByTi/+f/cI' | base64 -d - >file.png
```

I got *base64: invalid entry*.

If I add a "=" :

```
echo 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASAQMAAAByySynAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAP0lEQVQImWNgPm9gwAAmbM4bH4AQzAdAYiDC/rzxByTi/+f/cIL=' | base64 -d - >file.png
```

Then it is good. But alwas bad with imagecreatefromstring().

Could you tell us how did you get the base64 encoded content in javascript?

See this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#102113

**Edit**:
This code works...

```
<?php
    $data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASAQMAAAByySynAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAP0lEQVQImWNgPm9gwAAmbM4bH4AQzAdAYiDC/rzxByTi/+f/cIL';
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo $data;
?>
```