# Convert Image string to file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, upload

I have an image string in javascript and wish to post it to the PHP page in order to upload it. POST string variables don't seem to work so was wondering how I could do this like convert it to a file and post that way using javascript?

Comment: Passing strings generally work, no need to post a file (which you cant via javascript and standard file forms),

Comment: Related question is: [imagecreatefromstring issues with string passed from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650879/imagecreatefromstring-issues-with-string-passed-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it to base64, then do an xmlhttp request (or ajax request).

use window.atob to convert your string to base64.
look up how to perform a post ajax request.